# Third-order autonomous ODE - if $y' = p$, $y'' = p'p$, what is $y''' = $?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This question has been in my mind for quite some time.

Suppose we have an autonomous ODE which we can solve by substituting:

$$y' = p(y)$$. From there on, we know that $$y'' = p'_y \cdot y' $$

which is $$y'' = p'p$$

But what would the third derivative be? I tried a calculation and I got that

$$y''' = p''p^2 + p'p^2$$ but I'm not sure if I'm right or wrong!

Comment: Note that: $y’’’=(y’’)’$ and so on. You seem like you make the correct step.

Comment: Thanks! Is my answer correct, though?

Comment: You can use the chain rule in this manner; $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}=p\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}$, to easily compute the next derivative.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$y'''=(y'')'=\left(p'p\right)'=p\left(p''y'\right)+p'\left(p'y'\right)=p''p^2+p'^2p$$